# How to .remove() without affecting other list?

Tags: python, list

I want to try to remove elements from a list without affecting the previous list.

This will give you a better picture:

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list_two = list_one
>>> list_two.remove(2)
>>> list_two
[1, 3, 4]
>>> list_one  # <- How do I not affect this list?
[1, 3, 4]
```

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: What makes you think you have two lists?  (See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make `list_two` a copy of `list_one` rather than a reference to it:

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list_two = list_one[:]
>>> list_two.remove(2)
>>> list_two
[1, 3, 4]
>>> list_one
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Placing `[:]` after `list_one` creates a shallow copy of the list.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I was thinking list_two is a copy of it, not as a reference. :( Will try it now.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Will accept your answer after the time limit.

Comment: @guanhao97: `[:]` makes a copy using [slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation).  Another way to make a copy of `list_one` is to pass it to the list constructor `list(list_one)`.  A third way is to use the `copy` module, which unnecessary when all you need is a shallow copy of a list.

Comment: Alright, reading the answers at the answered question also helped. Thanks.